# ios autolayout dynamic UILabel height

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I have three `UILabels` whose positions are like below:

`[Label1] [Label2]`

`[Label3]`

`Label1` and `Label2` are in the same row and `Label3` is below them. All the labels will have a fixed width and will contain dynamic text, so their height will vary.

How do I make the `Label3` 10 points below the label which has a higher height using AutoLayout?

For example, if `Label1`'s height is 100 points, `Label2`'s height is 120 points (their Y positions are the same), then `Label3` should be 10 points below `Label2`, but if `Label1` is 120 points high and `Label2` is 100 points high, then `Label3` should be 10 points below `Label1`.

Comment: A constraint like 'Object  A should be N points below Object B' is extremely simple in Auto Layout. Can you show some code that you have tried first?

Comment: Yes, but I want Object A to be N points below the one which has a higher height, say Object B and Object C are in the same row, but their heights are not fixed (like some dynamic text), I want Object A to be N points below the Object which is higher.

Comment: Can you put Label1 and Label2 together in an NSView that will grow its size together with the labels? And then but Label3 under the NSView?

Comment: Hmm, that should be a workable solution, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply make constraints between both Label3->Label1 and Label3->Label2. Use *inequality* constraints. There will be only one way to satisfy both!

You will also need a top constraint for Label3; its `constant` should be very small and its `priority` should be very low. This will give the two inequality constraints something to "aim at".

Here is an example. This as achieved entirely without code - the buttons have code to add text to the labels, of course, but the constraints are configured entirely in Interface Builder; the labels are resizing, and the bottom label is moving down, *automatically*. (You can construct the same layout in code if you want to, naturally.)

[image]

Comment: This is not complete answer, because in that case bottom `label3` will still need Y constraint. I mean setting two inequality constraints cannot uniquely identify the frame of `label3`

Comment: Also added a screencast demonstrating that it works.

Comment: Thanks @matt for the solution. I am trying to achieve same, but missing same thing, can you please elaborate all the constraints you added?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to wrap top two `label`s to `UIView` and setup constraints so these `label`s fit all space inside that `view`. Then you simple add `vertical spacing constraint` to bottom `label3` with `constant = 10`. In that case top `view` will have size of larger `label` and will satisfy your conditions

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be an interesting exercise so I create a little test project. The gist of the code is below. You can just copy/paste it in the standard Single View iOS template.

(Note that I use SnapKit for programmatic Auto Layout because it is so much simpler than the UIKit API. I find it even much simpler than doing things in Xcode.)

The result is exactly the same as Matt's great screencast.

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let leftLabel = UILabel()
        leftLabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "addText:"))
        leftLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(leftLabel)
        leftLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        leftLabel.text = "All the world's a stage, and all the men and women merely players: they have their exits and their entrances; and one man in his time plays many parts, his acts being seven ages."
        leftLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(40)
            make.left.equalTo(self.view)
            make.right.equalTo(self.view.snp_centerX)
        }

        let rightLabel = UILabel()
        rightLabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "addText:"))
        rightLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(rightLabel)
        rightLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        rightLabel.text = "There is a tide in the affairs of men, Which taken at the flood, leads on to fortune. Omitted, all the voyage of their life is bound in shallows and in miseries. On such a full sea are we now afloat. And we must take the current when it serves, or lose our ventures."
        rightLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(40)
            make.right.equalTo(self.view)
            make.left.equalTo(self.view.snp_centerX)
        }

        let bottomView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(bottomView)
        bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        bottomView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.height.equalTo(20)
            make.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
            make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(leftLabel.snp_bottom)
            make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(rightLabel.snp_bottom)
        }
    }

    @objc func addText(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let label = recognizer.view as? UILabel {
            label.text = label.text! + " I like cheese."
        }
    }
}
```

Updated the code to add some additional text to the labels when tapped.

Comment: I don't think so. Add the functionality of my buttons (adding text to each of the labels in turn) and see if your `bottomView` continues to obey properly.

Comment: Works fine @matt ... See my updated example that adds text to the labels when you tap them. Curious why did you think it would not?

Comment: Because it seemed to me there's a missing constraint. However, it may be that I'm just wrong - sometimes Interface Builder is wrong about these things, and you can do in code things that Interface Builder won't let you do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all **remove height constraints** and set all 3 labels **vertical Content Compression Resistance Priority to 1000**. This is the most important part.

Then add vertical space from Label3 to Label 1, and set instead of Equal, Greater Than or Equal with priority say 500. Add same space constraint to Label2.

Last add constraint from Label3 to Top = 0, but set priority to 1.